# Sending location to BotBuilder Location

Tags: botframework

I am writing a Xamarin implementation of a bot channel using the DirectLine API and want to send my current location to the BotBuilder-Location plugin in a similar way to what Facebook Messenger does.

What format message do i need to send at the location prompt to get it to pick up my current location?

Answer (score 0):

I should have looked at the source code before posting. It seems that there is a special implementation for facebook channel so its not possible to 'simulate' facebook however with some slight tweaking of the location component you could get this to work but it is not possible using the component as is.